# Machine learning, speech recognition technologies for Sound of Animals interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, training, ai, interpretation

https://www.google.com/search?q=sound+of+animals&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=inv&sxsrf=ALeKk02xrn0-yn-FZSkidTogB4l4B_TH6A:1600539091086&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVhuTf6PXrAhWR4HMBHWS-AYQQ_AUoAXoECA8QAQ&biw=360&bih=592

https://www.google.com/search?q=sound+of+animals&source=lmns&bih=592&biw=360&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=inv&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjc79L07vXrAhWQYysKHSWxBr8Q_AUoAHoECAAQAw

https://www.instagram.com/p/CFVAPhNlTjh/?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet

https://www.instagram.com/p/CFVBPaqF00M/?utm_source=ig_web_button_share_sheet

Is it possible using AI , speech recognition & Machine learning technologies for interpreting Sound of Animals?

Input Dataset will be Sound files viz .wav format of animals.

Output will be recognising the sound and naming the animal.

Comment: 7th in the author's series of *How can we use machine learning in domain X ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very easily possible.

If you want quick output use teachable machine.

https://github.com/seth814/Audio-Classification Here is a sample git rep which you could use to enter into the domain. Be sure to label the sounds properly for higher efficiency.